# javaFX 2- Listner inside Contorller

Tags: controller, javafx-2, listener

Would like to use drag and drop feature in controller (see below). But as tableView.getParent() is NULL, my listner is not working. Can you pleae help here? I do not want to move code to main class.

```
public class CenterController implements Initializable {
@FXML public TableView<Swap> tableView;
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
loadDragDrop(tableView.getParent());
}
 public void loadDragDrop(final Node n){
        n.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                if (db.hasFiles()) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
                } else {
                    event.consume();
                }
            }
        });
    n.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();


                boolean success = false;
            event.setDropCompleted(success);
                event.consume();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the code that is not initialized in an runLater:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // youre code goes here ;-)
    }
});
```